# how to open display_errors=on in LAMP5

Tags: php, lamp

im a php newbie.
I just know I can modify php.ini(display_errors=on) in somewhere of windows system

but linux also hava(php.ini)?
sry, I try and i can't find it, anyone can help me? thx

Answer (score 1):

Just write simple script and check for php.ini path

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Here is the good tutorial: http://www.php-scripts.com/20050909/8/

Answer (score 0):

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>` will display (among other things) location of your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Within Linux this will normally be:

`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (if you are using PHP5, and Apache)

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` (if you are using PHP5 running on the command line).

Other common locations are:

```
/etc/php.ini
/etc/php/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/cli/php.ini
```

Best way is to create a PHP File with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and open this file using Apache2/CLI and this will display the php.ini file.

*Or add the following to the top of your PHP File:*

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: oh, thank you ,you are so pretty good at php! Also thans the others people who helped me, phpinfo() is very useful^^

Comment: hi, friends, i got a new trouble. I just sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and insert display_errors=on in the file.But looks like its dose not work >_<, so I sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart, but I got the same. programming is so difficult! what should i do now?

Comment: @zj: If it's too difficult for you to setup PHP on your system, either learn about it first or get help from someone who knows. That person then needs access to your system. So get in contact with some sysadmin you trust.

Comment: I can give you a hand with setting it up if you like... However this sounds like this is being overwritten somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

While developing use the following code at the top of your php files:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

When ready for production :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

This way, you don't need to modify the php.ini.